# Extract content from DBPedia's big dump file in .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdf, dbpedia, dotnetrdf

I want to extract labels, abstracts, categories and relevant dates to each article from [DBPedia dump file](http://live.dbpedia.org/dumps/).

I'm using [dotnetrdf](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/) and I want to save the extracted data to MS SQL database (I don't want to use triple stores like Virtuoso).

Due to the size of dump file, I can't load the dump file into memory.

Is there any solution to extract statements? The only way I can imagine is to split the dump file into smaller chunk files, is it the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually everything in dotNetRDF is designed to support streaming parsing, the most common use case happens to be loading stuff into our in-memory structures but even that uses the streaming parser subsystem under the hood.

See the [Advanced Parsing](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Reading%20RDF#!advanced-parsing) section of the Reading RDF documentation which introduces the [Handlers API](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Handlers%20API), this API gives users complete control over what happens to the data as it is produced by the parser.  So you can write a custom handler which receives the data as it is produced by the stream and puts it into your database.

Comment: I just took a closer look to your Handlers API link and this seems indeed to be what is needed here.